# Order Email: How do I replace subtotals that are equal to zero with "TBD"?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm working with the WooCommerce `email-order-items.php` and `email-order-details.php` template files. I'm trying to create some sort of 'if statement' that would replace item subtotal, total, and subtotal values with "TBD" (to be determined) if the value is equal to zero and then leave everything else as normal if the values are either negative or positive.

I've been trying to replace these lines in: `wp-contents/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/emails/`

```
'email-order-items.php': <?php echo $total['value']; ?>
'email-order-items.php': <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For item subtotal

```
if($itemsubtotal == 0) {
  $itemsubtotal = "TBD";
}
```

For total

```
if($total == 0) {
  $total = "TBD";
}
```

For subtotal

```
if($subtotal == 0) {
  $subtotal = "TBD";
}
```

EDIT 
Change this line

```html
<td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
```

TO

```html
<?php if($total['value'] != 0){ ?>

<td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td> 
<?php } else { ?>

<td class="td" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo "TBD"; ?></td> 


<?php } ?>
```

Similarly for other variables it can be done.

Comment: I tried your recommendation and it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I'm including it in the wrong place.

I've included the relevant recommended code in email-order-items.php & email-order-details.php within the <td>tags that display the totals and subtotals.

Should I just create a function for this? If so, how?

Comment: @trinib Can you paste the entire code in pastebin.com

Comment: here is the code: 
[link]http://pastebin.com/XRDQi1qQ
 
[link]http://pastebin.com/s5FGEQjM

Comment: @ Amit Its not exactly working. I'm getting TBD regardless to the order total. I've tried similar statements and it didn't work. I'm beginning to think there is an issue with the way the system is logging the subtotals and totals for edited orders. Thanks for all of your help. I'll keep working at it and post if I find a resolution.